# chunks_exact_mut threading lifetimes

Tags: multithreading, rust

The following code produces interesting results:

```rs
use std::thread;

fn main() {
    let mut handles = Vec::new();
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    
    for x in v.chunks_exact_mut(2) {
        let handle = thread::spawn(move || {
            println!("Here's a vector: {:?}", x);
        });
        
        handles.push(handle);
    }

    for h in handles { h.join().unwrap(); }
}
```

```rs
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:14
   |
7  |     for x in v.chunks_exact_mut(2) {
   |              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |              |
   |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
...
16 | }
   | - `v` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Why does 'chunking' `v` change the lifetime? Without 'chunking' `v`, the code performs correctly. So why now  does it throw an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that `thread::spawn` completely decouples the lifetime from the rest, as the thread might continue to run while `main` is already finished.

`x` is a reference to a variable in `main`, and there is no guarantee that `main` lives longer than the thread.

I think what you really want here is a threading helper library like [`rayon`](https://crates.io/crates/rayon), as they already solve those problems internally:

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];

    v.par_chunks_exact_mut(2).for_each(|x: &mut [i32]| {
        let thread_id = std::thread::current().id();
        println!("{:?}: Here's a vector: {:?}", thread_id, x);
    });
}
```

```
ThreadId(5): Here's a vector: [1, 2]
ThreadId(2): Here's a vector: [3, 4]
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I had no clue this library existed. I'll look into this more!

Answer (score 0):

Without "chunking" `v`, you're iterating over `Vec<i32>`. This iterator produces items of type `i32`, so, no references, no lifetimes, the requirements for `thread::spawn()` (specifically the `'static` requirement) are met.

`chunks_exact_mut()`, however, [is defined on slices](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact_mut) and gives iterator over `&mut [T]`, so it *does* have a reference. And since this reference refers `v`, which exists in `main()`, it is not `'static` and does not work.

You can observe the same problem if you'll iterate over `&v` instead of `v`, since that iterator gives you `&i32`s ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5125885b734d6a70b3b97f722d49f38e)):

```rust
error[E0597]: `v` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:7:14
   |
7  |     for x in &v {
   |              ^^
   |              |
   |              borrowed value does not live long enough
   |              argument requires that `v` is borrowed for `'static`
...
16 | }
   | - `v` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Other than that, I'd recommend using `rayon` as @Finomnis suggested.